# Get variable from address bar and then delete from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below which links to a page called deletepage.php which is in my FTP in the right directory. It adds the variable on the end from a database query, that bit works and it opens the page correctly:

```
<a href=\"http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/deletepage.php?plink=$link&user=$username\">X</a>
```

But now I have this code to run a query on that in the MySQL database but it doesn't actually delete it when it should be deleting it:

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "will", "blahblah");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); //check for database errors
}
$username = $_GET['user'];
mysql_select_db("themacsp_clipboy", $con);
$sql = ("DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink'] AND username='$username');
mysql_query($sql);
header("location: http://themacsplash.com/userfiles/$username");
?>
```

I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in >/data/www/vhosts/themacsplash.com/httpdocs/ClipBoy/deletepage.php on line 10

Line 10 is the $sql line (`$sql = ("DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink'] AND username='$username');`)

How would I fix this?

Comment: What about yesterdays advise of using an editor with syntax highlighting?

Comment: Will, please heed advice given in previous questions before continuing to make the same mistakes. Also please note that StackOverflow is _not_ a place to ask every possible question about PHP over and over; i.e. it's not a place to learn the language. Please get yourself a decent PHP book.

Comment: What editor would that be on mac?

Comment: There were some recommendations for Mac editors here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336515/free-php-editor-for-mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing some quotes again.

You should probably be doing it step by step, since it's less confusing:

```
$plink = (int)$_GET['plink'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM links WHERE link=$plink AND username='$username'";
```

Comment: thanks mario I will try your code now and come back and tell you if it worked :)

Comment: It's not actually deleting it from the database for soem reason?

Comment: Can't tell. Add `print mysql_error();` instead of the header redirect at the end.

Comment: The error is this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM links WHERE link=0 AND username='userfiles'' at line 1

Comment: So the username is right apart from there is a ' in front of it but it's not getting  a link when it should, I think it's because of that (int)

Comment: My bad. Copied your query verbatim. The `*` asterisk does not belong in the DELETE query.

Comment: Ok that has got me somewhere: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM links WHERE link=boom.com AND username=userfiles' at line 1

Comment: So what should go instead of the asterisk then? Should I just have nothing there?

Comment: Ok, I now just have a problem of this: Unknown column 'boom.com' in 'where clause' It should be not seeing the link as a column the column is called link and the value should be $plink (boom.com) How would I fix this?

Comment: Add single quotes around `'$plink'`, if it is not actually a numeric column. Also note that this is another SQL exploit, unless mysql_real_escape_string bla bla ..

Comment: Never mind I fixed it myself just needed '$plink' & '$username' thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Line should be

```
$sql = ("DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink'] . "AND username='$username'");
```

Also you should sanitize those $_GET strings with mysql_real_escape_string() to help avoid SQL injection hacks.

Comment: It's not actually deleting it from the database for some reason, please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink']." AND username='".$username."';";
```

You concatenated the strings and the variables in a wrong way. This'll do.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is in this line

```
<?php
//replace
//$sql = ("DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink'] AND username='$username');
//with
$sql = "DELETE * FROM links WHERE link = ".(int)$_GET['plink']. "AND username='".$username."'";
?>
```

Comment: It's not actually deleting it from the database for some unknown reason?